How would I get my javascript to choose the correct radio button in a php dynamically generated radio button list?
function statequery (theabbrev,thestate) {

    if (abbrev.value.length > 0) {
        enabledataentry();
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(){
        var x = 0;
        var statearray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (statearray.length > 0){
            stateabbrev.innerHTML=statearray[x].abbrev;
            statename.innerHTML=statearray[x].statename;
            pci.value=statearray[x].pci;
            pop.value=statearray[x].pop;

        radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName('stateradio');
        for (var x=0; x < radiobuttons.length; x++){
            if (radiobuttons[x].id === statearray.region) {
                radiobuttons[x].checked=true;
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "statesearch.php?abbrev="+theabbrev, true);
    xhttp.send();
      
  }
}

So this is my javascript above trying to select the correct radio button. The reason I have it this way is because the radio button list is dynamically created with a php query.
<?php foreach ($result as $row){ ?>
  <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $row['region'];?>" disabled name="stateradio"/>
  <label for="<?php echo $row['region'];?>">
  <?php echo $row['region'];?></label><br />
<?php } ?>

This is the php that generates the radio button list. However I can't get it to actually select the right button. There's no errors in the console so something is happening but not the way I want it to. Anyone know how to get this working?

What debugging have you done so far? Does it retrieve the expected values into statearray, for example?

What is the reason to have disabled in the radio button tag generated thru the PHP ?

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

statearray.region looks wrong, because in the rest of the code it's written as if statearray is an array of other objects. What does this.responseText actually contain, before you parse it? If we can see the JSON then we can confirm if this is actually the correct code to use to access that value. If that value existed inside statearray then your code would work perfectly, but I suspect that's not the case. It's far more likely, looking at the other code, that the "region" property actually exists in each of those objects inside the statearray.

Now...it looks like you expect statearray to only ever have one entry in it - is that right? Or at least, you're only interested in the first entry. I say that because the code which processes the statearray data simply looks once for values inside statearray[0], and doesn't loop. So, without seeing the responseText data, I'm going to guess that you can write if (radiobuttons[x].id === statearray[0].region) { to fix your problem.

[{"abbrev":"MO","0":"MO","statename":"Missouri","1":"Missouri","pci":61302,"2":61302,"pop":6196,"3":6196,"region":"Plains","4":"Plains"}]
this is what is contained in the this.responseText just as an example if I set the theabbrev value to MO. all the other inpur fields receive the proper information

For more clarification this is what statearray contains
{
"0": "MO",
"1": "Missouri",
"2": 61302,
"3": 6196,
"4": "Plains",
"abbrev": "MO",
"statename": "Missouri",
"pci": 61302,
"pop": 6196,
"region": "Plains"
}

For more clarification this is what statearray contains...that can't be correct. If responseText contains [{"abbrev":"MO","0":"MO","statename":"Missouri","1":"Missouri","pci":61302,"2":61302,"pop":6196,"3":6196,"region":"Plains","4":"Plains"}] then statearray will simply be the same data structure as an object (instead of a JSON string). It's not possible that statearray doesn't also have the array part, since the data is only parsed, not transformed. Your statement is 100% incorrect.

Did you try if (radiobuttons[x].id === statearray[0].region) { as I suggested?

function statequery (theabbrev,thestate) {
    if (abbrev.value.length > 0) {
        enabledataentry();
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(){
            var x = 0;
            var statearray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if (statearray.length > 0){
                stateabbrev.innerHTML=statearray[x].abbrev;
                statename.innerHTML=statearray[x].statename;
                pci.value=statearray[x].pci;
                pop.value=statearray[x].pop;
                var regionval = statearray[x].region;

                for (x=0; x < document.getElementsByName('stateradio').length; x++){
                    if (document.getElementsByName('stateradio').item(x).value==regionval){
                        document.getElementsByName('stateradio').item(x).checked=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "statesearch.php?abbrev="+theabbrev, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}

I figured out the solution my for loop was set up wrong and I also just created a new variable that contains the value of the statearray.region to help my code.
